# Only 1st letter of textarea going into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Thanks to everyone who's given me such great advice over the last several months.  I'm almost done with this project and I've learned so much.  But I'm kinda stumped using textarea.  I've googled and googled and can't find a solution.

This is not a public facing website so I'm not worried about sql injection and my organization uses an older version of PHP so I have to use mysql_query versus mysqli_query.

My problem is I have to echo two things from my database into a form so the user can edit and then update the database with the new inputs.  One is a small string of text that I display using input="text".  However the other is a longer string that lists a set of instructions so I'm using  because it's too much for a text box. However when I run my update query only the first letter of the textarea string gets updated into my database.  The textbox string works just fine. Here's my code

getrcs.php

```
<html>
<form>
<body>


<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
include ('database_connect.php');
$sql= "SELECT * FROM RDS_REFERENCE WHERE ID = '".$q."'";
$query_result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table>
<tbody>

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_result)) {
?>

<tr>
<td>
<label>Sub File Series Number/Title</label>
<input type="text" style="width:250px;" required="Required" name="sub_fs_num_tle1[]" value="<?php echo $row['SUB_FS_NUM_TITLE']?>/>
</td>




<td>
<label>Disposition Instructions</label>
<textarea name="disp_instr1" cols="40" rows="30" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica  sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><?php echo $row['Disposition_Instructions'] ?></textarea>
</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</tbody>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And update_rcs.php

```
<?php

include('database_connect.php');

foreach($_POST['id'] as $row => $id)


{
$sub_fs_num_tle1 = $_POST['sub_fs_num_tle1][$row];
$disp_instr1 = $_POST['disp_instr1'][$row];


$rcs_reference_update1 = "UPDATE RDS REFERENCE SET
                            SUB_FS_NUM_TITLE = '$sub_fs_num_tle1',
                            Disposition_Instructions = '$disp_instr1'
                            ";

mysql_query($rcs_reference_update1) or die("Could not update".mysql_error());

}

header('Location:rcs_maint.php');

?>
```

Comment: You're missing a single quote here: intval($_GET['q]);

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: You're not suppose to use unescaped double quotes inside a string: WHERE ID = '".$q."'

Comment: Your for loop uses `$_POST['id']` - I can't see any inputs in your form with the name of `id`

Comment: You have typos/errors all over the place so I'm assuming this isn't your actual code.  `$_POST['sub_fs_num_tle1]` `UPDATE RDS REFERENCE`.   What is the field type and length of the column in question?

Comment: Thank you, chris85.  That did the trick!!!  I'm ashamed I made that mistake I'm not new enough anymore to fall for that mistake!  If you find yourself in the Washington DC area, look me up.  I owe you a drink!

Comment: @Arioch9000 okay, posted that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your input is `name="disp_instr1"` the `$_POST['disp_instr1']` is a `string`, not an `array`. This means that `$_POST['disp_instr1'][$row]` will output whatever character `$row` is in that string.

Simple demo:

```
$test = 'test';
echo $test[0];
```

Outputs:

> t

Live Demo: https://eval.in/541463

To solve the issue use:

```
$disp_instr1 = $_POST['disp_instr1'];
```

Also SQL injections aren't the only reason to use parameterized queries. If a single quote needs to go to your db it will fail as is.